# How can I export the results of my script to file?

Tags: powershell, xml

I need to get some details out of hundreds of XML files that were written for reporting. The script below provides the correct results, but I want them in file, cvs, xls, or txt so I can provide a list of the database fields that are in use by these reports.

```
$get = get-childitem D:\Data\Desktop\Projects\Reports\Test -include *.xml -recurse 
ForEach ($xmlfile in $get)
{
$Report = $xmlfile
$Fields = [xml](Get-Content $Report)
$Fields.reportsettings.fieldlist.field | select @{ L = 'Description'; E = {$_.desc}},
                                                @{ L = 'Field Name'; E = {$_.criterion}},
                                                @{ L = 'Field ID'; E = {$_.id} } }
```

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: I figured it out. Here is the code that worked for me for future use. `$get = get-childitem D:\Data\Desktop\Projects\Reports\Test -include *.xml -recurse 
ForEach ($xmlfile in $get)
{
$Report = $xmlfile
$Fields = [xml](Get-Content $Report)
$data += $Fields.reportsettings.fieldlist.field | select @{ L = 'Description'; E = {$_.desc}},
            @{ L = 'Field Name'; E = {$_.criterion}},
            @{ L = 'Field ID'; E = {$_.id} } }
$data | Export-Csv fields.csv -NoTypeInformation`

Comment: please post that as an answer and mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little function called Out-ExcelReport. Just pipe anything to it, and it will open in Microsoft Excel - in case it is installed on your system:

```
function Out-ExcelReport
{
  param
  (
    $Path = "$env:temp\$(Get-Random).csv"
  )

  $Input | Export-Csv -Path $Path -Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture
  Invoke-Item -Path $Path
}
Get-Process | Out-ExcelReport
```

Answer (score 1):

The 4 best ways to dump objects (and lists of objects) to a file are:

- CSV - `ConvertTo-Csv` or `Export-Csv`
- HTML - `ConvertTo-Html`
- JSON - `ConvertTo-Json`
- XML - `ConvertTo-Xml`

---

Keep in mind that `convertto-*` will just take the object, serialize, and spit out text. So you would have to use `out-file`

```
$test = "I am a object"
$test | ConvertTo-Xml | out-file "C:\test.xml"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try some command builtin in PowerShell, like [Export-csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx), [ConvertTo-XML](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730921.aspx), [Out-File](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176924.aspx), [Export-Clixml](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176824.aspx).

Example:

```
Get-Process | Export-Csv process.txt
```

Comment: Yes I've tried those unfortunately it only returns 1 line from the very first xml file. If I use those like that I'd need help looping it through all of the files to get the results I need. 

$data = $Fields.reportsettings.fieldlist.field | select @{ L = 'Description'; E = {$_.desc}},
            @{ L = 'Field Name'; E = {$_.criterion}},
            @{ L = 'Field ID'; E = {$_.id} } 
            } 
$data | Export-Csv fields.csv